# I have this code trying to execute on sql posture and keep geeting an error

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

```
@app.route("/registered",methods=["POST"])
def registered():
    username = request.form.get("user_name")
    Password = request.form.get("password")
    First_name = request.form.get("first_name")
    Last_name = request.form.get("last_name")
    Email = request.form.get("email")
    confirm_password= request.form.get("confirm_password")
    if confirm_password != Password:
        Error_Message="Password Don't mach"
        return render_template("register.html",Error_Message=Error_Message)
    if confirm_password == Password:
        if username is not None and Password is not None and First_name is not None and Last_name is not None and Email is not None:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, First_Name, Last_Name, Password, Email) VALUES (:username,:First_Name,:Last_Name,:Password,:Email)",
                {"username": username, "First_Name":First_name, "Last_Name":Last_name, "Password":Password, "Email":Email})
            db.commit()

        else:
            Error_Message="Password Don't mach"
            return render_template("register.html",Error_Message=Error_Message)
    return render_template("success.html")
```

and this is the error keep getting

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "first_name" of relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO users (username, First_Name, Last_Name, Password...

and this is my table

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW1WD.png)

can you help me please figure this out

Comment: Maybe you should point to the full path to your table: "myschema"."mytable". Double check it by creating the table in the default schma. HTH.